# Ionic App, silent Authentication or refresh token to allow user stay signed in

Tags: ionic-framework, auth0

I just created a new Ionic app and using Auth0 for user login and registrations. I have .net core backend.

I am following the Ionic quick start guide https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ionic4/01-login and everything is working ok. I use new Universal login.

The issue I have is users get logged out after the access_token has expired. I previously used Silent Authentication and refresh tokens in two different apps, however I am unable to find a sample code like quick start guide for either. I have an angular website too. Hence my users can either use mobile app or Angular website to login. I would appreciate any help to keep my users loggedin, in both website and ionic mobile app please.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, Auth0 doesn't have many samples for acquiring refresh tokens from application frontends, which is typically what I would consider ionic/angular to be used for. Obviously, you could be building a "native" style application with either of those, but frontend auth is sometimes a little messy and insecure because the client has your code and you usually need to implement some kind of middleware.

It looks like the ionic quickstart uses auth0-js which [defaults to an implicit flow](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-cordova/issues/120), which would confirm my hunch above.

I personally pass the refresh token logic off to my backend, and let the backend function as my "middleware". [You can find some basic code samples for backends/native apps here.](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-tokens/use-refresh-tokens) I use the code-grant flow typically, but you could use PKCS.

The long and short is, I don't think you're going to find sample code on that, but you could hack something together with something like axios if you wanted to go the middleware route, or you could go backend with your auth.